# Google Extensions API 2

Tags: api, google-chrome

I have a problem. I had a app on the manifest v1.
But now it tells me to change it to v2. But it gives me an error like:

> - Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>     Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>     chrome-extension-resource:".

I tried to change in the manifest:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "jquery-1.7.1.min.js",
    "plugin.js"
]
```

But in the html code, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="plugin.js"></script>
```

How do I put it now? Should I delete that? If i delete it won't run! My popup doesn't even opens anymore :|

Hope you understood my problem, thanks

(I'll thank more if someone gave an example of API v2 using javaScript to download :) )

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that there is some script being executed directly inside your HTML page, not included via an external javascript file.

For example:

`<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>` embedded inside your html file is an inline script. The correct way to do it would be

`<script type="text/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>` .

Your file hello.js would include `alert('hello');`

I hope this helps.